# Anyway for ADO to read updated data from a read-only excel file before save? (VBA)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado, readonly

I am using the following code to read data from Sheet1 of SAME Excel sheet. I load the data into the return array. The Excel sheet file has "read only" checked and is always opened in "READ ONLY" mode.

**The issue is** that if I change any of the data on Sheet1, because the file is opened as "read only", it won't be reflected in the ADO query. ADO Continues to output what is in the "saved" file and ignores what has been updated in the temp read only version.
For example the below pulls value "Col5:6" from cell "E6". If I replace the value to be "test", ADO still outputs "Col5:6"

**How can I make ADO read the current data on Sheet1 without having to "save as"?**

```vb
Sub sbADO()
    Dim sSQLSting As String
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
    Dim returnArray

    DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBPath _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    Conn.Open sconnect
    sSQLSting = "SELECT * From [Sheet1$] "

    mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn

    returnArray = mrs.GetRows

    mrs.Close
    Conn.Close

    Debug.Print returnArray(4, 4) '>> "Col5:6"

End Sub
```

Comment: I would use a public variable, blnWorksheetDirty as Boolean, then on the worksheet change event, i'd set this to true if changes made, then if there were, save a temp copy and query that, if not, use what you have.

Comment: Isn't there a way for ADO to be instructed to read from the temp data in the read only version? or must it always read from the version as last saved?

Comment: Why do you want to use ADODB when it seemingly requires you to save the file some place first (which you want to avoid)? Why don't you just "grab" the data into an array and skip the ADO connection? It's only two lines of VBA code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000617/how-to-copy-selected-range-into-given-array/18000989#18000989 If that's not an option then how about using a different back-end like a DB server for the data?

Comment: @Ralph I use ODBC to pull a bunch of data into a table thats in the file. Then I have some form checkboxes for user options. The user can choose what data they want to see on output sheet. Based on user input ADO writes special sql using the where statement and queries my big (in file) data table, such that only specific things get loaded to the return array. Simply loading all into an array would be useless in this case. I could loop through using VBA but that is such a slow way to feed data to my array.

Comment: I could just load everything in one fell swoop into the array and then carefully roll through it to build the output page but the complexity of the If statements needed to sort would be tremendous.

Answer (score 1):

You can't read unsaved changes from Excel worksheet with ADO since the unsaved data is located in the memory (RAM, and probably swap file), and ADO designed to connect to DB **files** or server-based DBs.

If you believe that SQL is the only way, and your `WHERE` clause is quite simple then you can use an ADO Recordset built in functionality for filtering and sorting, without making connection. Do the following:

1. Get the value of the source range in XML format, fix field names.
2. Create XML DOM Document and load the XML string.
3. Create ADO Recordset and convert the document.
4. Make necessary filtering and sorting. Note, there is [some limitations on filter criteria](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275540.aspx) syntax.
5. Process the resulting recordset further, e. g. output to another worksheet.

There is an example of the code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FilterSortRecordset()
    Dim arrHead
    Dim strXML As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objXMLDoc As Object
    Dim objRecordSet As Object
    Dim arrRows

    ' get source in XML format
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        arrHead = Application.Index(.Range("A1:G1").Value, 1, 0)
        strXML = .Range("A2:G92").Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)
    End With

    ' fix field names
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrHead)
        strXML = Replace(strXML, "rs:name=""Field" & i & """", "rs:name=""" & arrHead(i) & """", 1)
    Next

    ' load source XML into XML DOM Document
    Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    objXMLDoc.LoadXML strXML

    ' convert the document to recordset
    Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objRecordSet.Open objXMLDoc

    ' filtering and sorting
    objRecordSet.Filter = "City='London' OR City='Paris'"
    objRecordSet.Sort = "ContactName ASC"

    ' populate another sheet with resulting recordset
    arrRows = Application.Transpose(objRecordSet.GetRows)
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
        For i = 1 To objRecordSet.Fields.Count
            .Cells(1, i).Value = objRecordSet.Fields(i - 1).Name
        Next
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(arrRows, 1), UBound(arrRows, 2)).Value = arrRows
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

The sourse data on `Sheet1` is as follows:

[image: src]

Then I got the result on `Sheet2`:

[image: result]