# find function with two criteria in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search the data with two conditions. Eg: column "A" should match with str (string) and column "J" should contain "Completed"
With the below coding, I am able to put only one condition.  Please advise me as to what changes are required to add a second condition.

```
 Set Rng = .Find(What:=str,After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count),LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
```

Comment: You'll need to do two separate searches. The find method can be quite slow if not optimize.  You should post your actual code.

Comment: Create disconnected recordset, populate it with values from the range, apply filter, and get resulting records from recordset. Here is the [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36189658/2165759).