# Matching information in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Users input specific information on (Sheet1) that is Workflow, server, where, start time, dependency and execution time.

I have a chart that has those names in headers.

I need to look for the information the user put in. I have tried using `VLookup` but that only works for one criteria. Is there something else I could use?

This is my code:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    'Copy the ticket number'
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c3").Copy _
      Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("b2")
    Call CopyTable
    Call FINDSAL
End Sub

Sub CopyTable()
    '
    ' CopyTable Macro to sheet 3
    '
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("D1:I38").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("C4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
End Sub

Sub FINDSAL()
    'looking for the specific word'
    Dim E_name As String
    E_name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").Value
    sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(E_name, Sheet3.Range("c4:h41"), 1, False)
    MsgBox sal
End Sub
```

Comment: Would [`Index/Match` with multiple criteria](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/) work?

Comment: Create disconnected recordset, populate it with values from the range, apply filter, and get resulting records from recordset. Here is the [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36189658/2165759).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FINDSAL()
'looking for the specific word'
Dim E_name As String
E_name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").Value
if instr(ename,Sheet3.Range("c4:h41")) > 0 then
  msgbox Ename & " was found in the range. All range text is " &     Sheet3.Range("c4:h41") 
msgbox "Set sal as whatever you're trying to get out of this..."
end if
MsgBox sal
```

End Sub