# How to load Arrays from Excel Sheet into VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a function which translates exam points into a grade.
If i define the Arrays inside the function it works as expected. But i would like to give the user the option to use his own point/grade structure as a parameter of the function.

I tried this to load an Array from the spreadsheet

This one gives me an Value error in excel.

```
Function GRADE(Points, ParamArray Pattern())

 If IsMissing(Pattern) Then Pattern = Array(90.5, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35)

 Grades = Array(1, 1.3, 1.7, 2, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 3.3, 3.7, 4, 5)
 
 For i = LBound(Pattern) To UBound(Pattern)
  If Points >= Pattern(i) Then
   GRADE = Grades(i)
   Exit For
  End If
 Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000617/how-to-copy-selected-range-into-given-array

Comment: You call this as UDF? Probably you need to define the Pattern-Parameter as Range.

Comment: You're going to need to show us how you intend to call the function. Is the ParamArray going to be loaded with a range - eg `=GRADES(A1,B1:B10)` , or as an array - eg. `=GRADES(A1, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 65, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35)`

Comment: 1. Should all the time `Pattern` and `Grades` contain 11 elements?  If not, is there a logic based on which to build `Grades` according to `Pattern` input? 2. As suggested above, you can replace `ParamArray` parameter with a range (or to an array). `GRADE(Points, rngPat As Range)` And pass it to the function as "A2:A12". Then, declare `Pattern As Variant` and use `Pattern = rngPat.Value`. And obtaining a 2D array you should use `If Points >= Pattern(i, 1) Then`...

Comment: @CLR That's correct. I deleted that part of my comment...

Comment: I think maybe you don't understand `ParamArray`. How are you inputting your Array? `=grade(22,50,40,30,20,10,5,2,1)` works OK, as does using individual cell references: `=grade(22,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8)`. However, if you are using a multi-cell Range for an argument to Pattern, you need to detect that and then extract each value in the range reference to your pattern array in your code. And, of course, ParamArray can take a variety of inputs. eg `=grade(50,B2:B8,90,95) would also be valid input. You just have to figure out what's what in your code.

Comment: Thank you guys! The way with Range worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

### Grading System UDF

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Function GRADE(ByVal Points As Double, ParamArray Pattern()) As Double

    If IsMissing(Pattern) _
        Then Pattern = Array(90.5, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35)
    Dim Grades(): Grades = Array(1, 1.3, 1.7, 2, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 3.3, 3.7, 4, 5)
 
    Dim Result As Double, i As Long
 
    For i = LBound(Pattern) To UBound(Pattern)
        If Points >= Pattern(i) Then Result = Grades(i): Exit For
    Next i
    
    If Result = 0 Then Result = 6
    
    GRADE = Result

End Function
```